# How do I terminate request processing when implementing custom authentication in MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

In my MVC2 application I want most requests to use Forms authentication and requests to some specific URIs to use my custom authentication. In order to do so I added `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate()` method and inside I check the URI and if it's one of those exclusive URIs I want to check the username and password in the request headers.

The problem is how to terminate the request if the credentials provided are wrong.

I tried:

```
HttpContext context = args.Context;

context.Response.Write( "Wrong credentials" );
context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
context.Response.End();
```

but once that happens the request is forwarded to the URI that is specified in web.config under

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn"/>
</authentication>
```

I want the request to be terminated - so that the response is sent to the client and the connection is closed. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you send 401 status code the Forms Authentication module intercepts this code and automatically redirects to the logon page. The correct way to handle authentication in ASP.NET MVC is using the `[Authorize]` attribute. And if you don't want it to redirect to the login page but instead show some view you could write a custom authorize attribute and override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/unauthorized.cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

In addition to overriding the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` you could override the [AuthorizeCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore.aspx) method which allows you to perform custom authentication.

Comment: I don't want to redirect to the view - those addresses are for programmatic requests, so I must feed some magic predefined strings to the response and close it. So I want no interception on Forms Auth module.

Comment: @sharptooth, if you don't want to redirect to a view simply return an empty result or whatever the client expects: `filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();`

Comment: Okay, but how do I invoke my custom authentication this way?

Comment: @sharptooth, I am not sure about what custom authentication you are talking about but you could always override the `AuthorizeCore` method on this custom attribute and do whatever custom authentication you want.

Comment: Inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute and overriding `AuthorizeCore` worked. Could you please add overriding `AuthorizeCore` into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to secure your application is to use the `PrincipalPermissionAttribute`, you can apply this to the whole controller, or just actions on the controller. E.g.

`[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Administrator")]
public class AdminController : Controller 
{
    ...
}`

or

`[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Administrator")]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
{
    ...
}`

You can find more information [in this article](http://coderjournal.com/2008/03/securing-mvc-controller-actions/).

Comment: If you read the comments, you find that this really isn't a good idea because PrincipalPermssion does not use CodeSecurity.  It's a bit more low level and requires you to implement a bunch of other things.